# Make basic search in array with if and else

Tags: function, search

I am trying to make a basic search function. if input.value does exist in array alert message, if not, push it to array ans show in HTML. I think I have already most of work done, but there is somewhere a mistake. Thank you in advance for your help guys .)

```
<div id="main">

<input id="inputForMyDict">

<button id="ButtonForInputSave" onclick="buttonSave()">Speichern</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>

<script>

var myDict = [];

var buttonSave = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < myDict.length; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value = myDict[i]) {
    alert("your input is already in your list");
  } else {
    myDict.push(document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myDict;
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there are 2 ways to do a comparison.

1. **Strict Equality Operator** `===` strict equality operator.
2. If you are not sure about the exact datatype for the values being compared, then you can use the `==` for comparison.

The line `document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value = myDict[i]` needs comparison operator and not the assignment operator (=). So you need to replace the `=` with either `==` or  `===`.

so your javascript code should look like

```
var buttonSave = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < myDict.length; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value == myDict[i]) {
  // If you know exact data type, then use the below line instead and comment the above line  if (document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value === myDict[i]) {
    alert("your input is already in your list");
  } else {
    myDict.push(document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myDict;
  }
}
}
```

**Update1:** Based on the clarification, provided by comments, you don't need to have a for loop to check for existence of element in array. Javascript provides a convenient way by `indexOf` method on an array. indexOf method check for the existence of an element in an array and returns the index of the element in the Array. However, if the element is not found then it returns -1.

Full code below which should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="main">

<input id="inputForMyDict">

<button id="ButtonForInputSave" onclick="buttonSave()">Speichern</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</div>

<script>

var myDict = [];

var buttonSave = function() {
//for (var i = 0; i < myDict.length; i++) {
  var valueInTextbox = document.getElementById("inputForMyDict").value;
  if(myDict.indexOf(valueInTextbox) > -1){
    alert("your input is already in your list");
  } else {
    myDict.push(valueInTextbox);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myDict;
  }
}
//}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you are right about the "==" however it still has not resolved the problem. my code still does not work. I checked array via console.log but it does not contain any strings after pressing button.

Comment: the check on the `for` loop for the `i < myDict.length` would always be false as the myDict is empty. So, the code would never reach the If-else conditions

Comment: Yes, that is something I figurred out as well already, therefore I have put a string in the array "zero". but it still does not work properly. Just copy and paste the code and you will see. the loop has some bug.

Comment: That helps a lot! I did not know about the indexOf.. Thank you very much for your help, Agalo! :)